# Adjust bottom margin of a listing environment

Tags: spacing, listings

I use the following settings for code listings.

```
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\lstset{language=Java,
    keywordstyle=\color{RoyalBlue},
    basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{Green}\ttfamily,
    rulecolor=\color{black},
    upquote=true,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
    stepnumber=1,
    numbersep=8pt,
    showstringspaces=false,
    breaklines=true,
    frameround=ftff,
    frame=single,
    belowcaptionskip=.25\baselineskip
}
```

I want to add some white space at the bottom of the listing to separate it from the paragraph. How can I adjust the bottom margin below the code listing?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use `belowskip` (p. 16 and 28 of the `listings` [manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/listings)):

> **Vertical space** The keys `aboveskip` and `belowskip` control the vertical space above and below displayed listings. Both keys get a
>   dimension or skip as value and are initialized to `\medskipamount`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\lstset{language=Java,
    keywordstyle=\color{RoyalBlue},
    basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{Green}\ttfamily,
    rulecolor=\color{black},
    upquote=true,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
    stepnumber=1,
    numbersep=8pt,
    showstringspaces=false,
    breaklines=true,
    frameround=ftff,
    frame=single,
    belowcaptionskip=5em,
    belowskip=3em,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
// Hello.java
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Hello extends JApplet {
    public void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {
        g.drawString("Hello, world!", 65, 95);
    }
}
\end{lstlisting}
This is my text.

\end{document}
```

[image]