# avoid empty vert space after lstlisting

Tags: listings

After some `\begin{lstlisting} ... \end{lstlisting}`, LaTeX adds some additional vertical space. How can I avoid that?

[image: shot]

Comment: please provide a MWE, which produces the given output

Comment: The answers [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32047/how-to-remove-the-skip-after-a-listing-when-parskip-is-increased-with-basel) or [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50107/adjust-bottom-margin-of-a-listing-environment) might help out.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Thanks to Scott H for the [reference](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32047/how-to-remove-the-skip-after-a-listing-when-parskip-is-increased-with-basel). It didn't directly helped me but it pointed out that the problem was my redefinition of `\parskip` and `\baselineskip`.

I'm using this now and it mostly works:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[belowskip=-0.8 \baselineskip]
CyclotomicField(order).gen().coordinates_in_terms_of_powers()
\end{lstlisting}
```

Comment: You should never redefine `\baselineskip` directly in latex (use `\linespread` or a font size command) and `\parskip` can only be changed with some care.

Comment: Actually, the space above/below any listing is given by `\medskipamount`. See the [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) (section **2.7 Layout elements**, p 15, under the heading **Vertical space**).

Comment: The extra space is also present when you increase linespacing with the \onehalfspacing command from the setspace package (needed in my case because of a specific body font with large ascenders and descenders, and a long line length).

Comment: How to use this at the same time with [language=SomeLang] ?

Comment: There is still space occurs after the `lstlisting` @Albert

Comment: Albert solution woks with `\begin{lstlisting}[belowskip=-1.5 \baselineskip]` @ alper

Comment: There is also `aboveskip` option which can be used to control space above the listing block.