# Vertical cell padding in tabular with equations and listings

Tags: tables, equations, listings

Vertical cell padding in the bottom of each cell in `tabular` with equations and listings is too large in cells containing one or more equations or listings. How do I get rid of this extra space?

Apparently, I can add `\vspace{-1em}` to the problematic cells, but is there a more general way, e.g., a command in the header of the tabular environment?

I have been trying various combinations of `belowskip` (the parameter of `\lstset`) and  `\belowdisplayskip`. They have an unfortunate effect if there are multiple equations or listings in the cells. `\arraystretch` also seems to have an unfortunate effect within the cell for the various combination I have tried.

I would also like to have it working for the `longtable` environment. For the combinations I have tried it seems to behave similar to `tabular` wrt. my problem.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,listings}

\begin{document}

\lstset{belowskip=0em}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}

\begin{tabular}{ p{3.5cm} | p{3.5cm} }
  \hline
  Equation
  \begin{equation*}
    \begin{bmatrix}
      1 \\
      2 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
  \end{equation*}
  &
    Some code
    \begin{lstlisting}
a = 1 + 2
    \end{lstlisting}
    Add
    \begin{lstlisting}
a = a + 2
    \end{lstlisting}
    % \vspace{-1em}
  \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/118730/54817

Comment: @SalimBou I am aware of several similar SO questions. I have not been able find a combination that would work for me.